# Trying to Line Up Text To An Image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a website that was developed using iWeb where you can drag any object anywhere and make really nice websites.  However it does not easily work well with websites that need a database.  Because of this I am rewriting a website using Ruby on Rails 3.2.3, CSS3, Bootstrap 2.0, etc.

Here is the link to the website I am rewriting.  http://www.iktusnetlive.com/Home.html

I am trying to replicate the portion where the blue camera with LIVE in yellow is in the header.  I want to line up text to where the camera lens is.  The graphic is 60X55. I have tried for a few hours playing with line-height, padding-top and other CSS options but I could not get the text to move down.

Here is my HTML code that includes the graphic and text I want to line up with the camera lens:

```
<p class="align-center"><span id="camera-text"><span id="text-bold"><%= image_tag("live_transparent.png", alt: "iktusNETlive") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;To view FREE LIVE STREAMING VIDEO, you will need to create a FREE ACCOUNT and be logged in.</span></span></p>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
#camera-text {font-size: 15px; vertical-align: middle; color: @red;}

.align-center { text-align: center; }

#text-bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

I wonder if this is something that I will be able to do.  As you can see I have a gradient as my page background.  I do not know if this is possible using Bootstrap, CSS3 or HTML5.  I would have created a table back in the day and use cell padding and other options that are no longer available in HTML5 apparently.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a example image, showing how you would like things to line up?

Comment: It is included in the header of the link I include in the post.  There  is a blue old time movie camera image with the word Live in yellow.  To the right of it is text aligned with the camera lens.  I am trying to stay away from using a table if possible.  Even so I am unfamiliar with how to do them in HTML5.  I have done them with HTML but most of the options appear to have been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can generally center block level items in CSS like this:

```
.some-class {
    display: block; /* needed if you'd like to center an inline element */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Setting the right and left margins to auto does the trick.

Try [absolute positioning](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/absolutepositioning) When you need to get really specific:

If you're building a basic website, Ruby on Rails and Twitter Bootstrap are overkill and will only complicate things. You might try WordPress as you get the hang of it.

Comment: I am rewriting a website to add a PostgreSQL database.  I decided to use Ruby on Rails to hopefully accommodate a high amount of traffic after doing some research on what web tools are being used for Twitter and other high traffic websites.

Absolute positioning may work for me.  I hope I can use percentages with it.  I have been using px values and it is putting the text where I want.  I want to use percentages to get them to be in the same position for people using different monitor settings.  Thanks so much.  I will post again when I complete this task.  I just saw something I need to fix

Comment: I just modified my CSS code to use absolute positioning with percentages. When I deploy the application I will check on other displays to make sure the text shows up in the same spot.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I have checked my absolute positioning on different browsers.  They do not line up at the same spot.  I was trying to avoid using a table but it looks like I may have to.  Maybe your first suggestion will work there.  At least I have options to look at.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I ended up putting the image & text in a 2 cell table.  In the text cell I used padding-top to line up the text to the camera lens.  I may rewrite this code to remove the table when I gain more experience with CSS.